How do I get sections hierarchy on a page using Azure AI Document Intelligence?
I have a multipage document. I want to create a section hierarchy on a particular page or pages. I am using Azure AI Document Intelligence, and its giving varying result, often incorrect.
In the top level layout.sections is giving sections that are spread over pages. I cannot get elements on page number N. For example, I want to be able draw a page like this one

layout.page doesn't have section information,
layout.section doesn't have page information.
Please help.
